# PictureBox array index or tag reference

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Need to know the index and tag of a clicked PictureBox array element in Visual Basic 2010.
**Tag** and **Index** are dimmed as Public Integer variables. **Gbox** is name of PictureBox array. **Tag = sender.tag** works.  **Index = NameofArray.Indexof(sender as PictureBox)** does not work nor does **Index = clicked.Indexof(sender as PictureBox)**

```
    Private Sub Gbox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clicked As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    SelectedColor.Image = clicked.Image
    Tag = sender.tag
    Index = Gbox.IndexOf(sender as picturebox)  'Does not work
    Index = clicked.Indexof(sender as PictureBox)  ' Does not work        
    End Sub
```

I need to use the pre-assigned tag and index in a calculation.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would return its index, try this out

```
Index = Array.IndexOf(Gbox, sender)
```

[ **Note:** The above code will return the `first occurance` of the `object` in that `array`(From its `lower bound` - 0). And by the way it will return `-1` if the `searched object` not present in that particular `array` ]

Comment: Many thanks **RajaPrabhu**.  Your solution was simple and worked.  I will mark my question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer came from **RajaPrabhu** and my thanks go to him. His solution was simple and resolved several issues.

```
    Index = Array.IndexOf(Gbox, sender)
```

I did find another solution for this particular program, but thanks to **RajaPrabhu** I will be able to implement his solution in several other instances.

Here was the solution I found: 
Part of the problem was that the user could change their mind and make a different selection thereby overwriting the tag attribute of the selection.  Solved by using the tag attribute of the selection and then also the tag attribute of the placement in the larger array.  The larger array tag attribute was assigned a tag equal to the creating loop increment, which was also the index.

This got the tag of the selected item:

```
    Private Sub SC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Dim clicked As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
       SelectedColor.Image = clicked.Image
       Tag = sender.tag
    End Sub
```

Then this got the tag, which was the index, of the placement array:

```
    Private Sub Gbox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Dim clicked As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
       clicked.Image = SelectedColor.Image
       Index = sender.tag
    End Sub
```

Tested and used the output here:

```
    Private Sub Guess_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Guess.Click
       Dim PositionInRow As Integer
       TextBox1.Text = "Tag: " + Tag.ToString + ", Index: " + Index.ToString
       'MessageBox.Show(index.ToString)
       Row = Row + 1
       PositionInRow = Index Mod 5 + 1 'there are 13 rows of 5 positions
       'more code.......
    End Sub
```

Thanks for taking the time to review.  This is a great site, full of very useful information and helpful associates.